# Java: Making a simple interactive cli app

Tags: java, command-line-interface, interactive

I want to make a simple interactive CLI app in Java. The user will type commands like `add ...` `show ...` but I am not sure how to set up the commands. Should i have a class for each command or something different?

Comment: I recommend [Java The Complete Reference, 9th edition](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/java-the-complete/9780071808552/). I assume you could find the .pdf for free on Google if you wanted. Your question shows me that you are inexperienced with OOP, so this book would be the best thing to get you started. Also, you should know that the question you posted does not comply with Stack Overflow's guidelines. Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

please take a look at this: https://picocli.info/. It gives both the library for parsing the cli arguments and also some code examples for structuring.

[Apache commons CLI](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/usage.html) is another Java library for arg parsing.

Typically your cli starts with a single executable program installed on the system, instead of multiple as you indicated (add, show, etc). The executable can take arguments which instruct it to do different things.

So you should have:

- `$ mycli add`
- `$ mycli show`.

For real examples, check out the CLI from [aws](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-commandstructure.html) and [docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/docker/).